# show volume informations in tabular view

Tags: linux, text-formatting, volume, lsblk, powershell

I'm trying to save on linux powershell core 6.1 information about the volumes in a variable. Best in the same or similar format as it is possible on windows.

[image: Volume information on windows]

But i am unable to achiev this kind of tabular thing. I want the following output to be seperated by commas, and the attributes to be seperated by semicolons (Like in the first screenshot)

[image: Volume information on linux]

This is the desired format:

[image: desired result]

Answer (score 0):

Something close (more like csv).

```
lsblk -io KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL,FSTYPE,STATE  | sed -e 's/  */;/g' -e 's/$/,/g'

KNAME;TYPE;SIZE;MODEL;FSTYPE;STATE,
sda;disk;238.5G;SKhynix_SC300_HFS256G32MND-3210A;running,
sda1;part;256M;vfat;,
sda2;part;16G;swap;,
sda3;part;222.2G;btrfs;,
sdb;disk;1.8T;ST2000LX001-1RG174;running,
sdb1;part;500G;btrfs;,
sdb2;part;500G;btrfs;,
sdb3;part;100G;btrfs;,
```

Or you could remove the headers with

```
lsblk -nio KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL,FSTYPE,STATE  | sed -e 's/  */;/g' -e 's/$/,/g'
```

Comment: hope this is not the desired solution for OP... recheck the question..

Comment: @Pierre-Alain TORET Thanks for the answer but it is not quite the formatting i need.